# openssl session tickets - SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_ticket_key_cb callback being called with enc=1 only

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

On server application, I'm trying to make tls session tickets to work using openssl 1.1. Following the explanation in https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_ticket_key_cb.html

On requests, I can see that the callback is being called at the ssl handshake process with parameter "enc=1"
as expected for first request making new session, the function executes as explained on openssl above link and returns value of 1.

However, in successive requests, the callback is still being called with "enc=1" which indicates that the client did not send a ticket. So the session resumption did not take place.

Tried to use both tls 1.2 / 1.3 server methods, but was no different behavior.

On the ssl ctx initiation, should there be other settings  beside "SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_ticket_key_cb"?
Any ideas on how to debug?

Also, since in that example, the "ssl" pointer is not being used at all, so not clear to me how/where is the ticket being written to the handshake final response.

Thanks

Comment: using  s_client -connect www.example.com:443 I can see that two tickets are issued by the server as expected. but still using chrome / firefox browser. callback allays being called with "enc=1"

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to debug?

Do a packet capture and check if a ticket is sent from the server to the client. If this is not the case something is wrong with creating the ticket. If the ticket is sent to the client check if the client sends the same ticket back. If not then something is wrong with the client, like the client not supporting session tickets.

> ... since in that example, the "ssl" pointer is not being used at all, so not clear to me how/where is the ticket being written to the handshake final response.

The newly created ticket is returned by modifying the inputs `key_name` and `ctx`. Since these are pointers to buffers and structures modifications will be reflected back to the caller. The SSL object if only needed if somehow one want to decide what to do based on the current SSL session, which is usually not the case.

Comment: Thanks @steffen-ullrich, will try to check if the ticket is being sent back.
regarding the key_name, ctx. thought it probably the case since there is no other choice :)